# Trick to quickly know if a family of vectors is spanning?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am reviewing my Linear Algebra course and we are currently working on the subject of Basis.
A family of vectors is a basis of a vector space if :

1. It is composed of linearly independent vectors
2. The vectors are spanning.

I know that in a basis, there is a notion of minimality. It means that I have to have the right number of vectors.

My question : **is there a quick way to know if a family is spanning** or I always need to go for the gaussian elimination on the linear combination of the family = vector($x_1, ..., x_n$) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimension of the space is $n$ over some field $\mathbb{F}$.

Then, the set contains at least $n$ linearly independent vectors from $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ must be a spanning set of that space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ linearly independent vectors in n-space, these vectors from a basis. No check for spanning is necessary.